# Commands registration/execution file?

Tags: shell, makefile, command, command-line-interface, package.json

With node.js and npm, we can use package.json to alias scripts.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "greet": "echo hi,"
  }
}
```

```sh
$ npm run greet foo

hi, foo
```

With Makefile, a similar thing can be possible.

```
greet:
    echo hi,
```

```sh
$ make greet

hi,
```

Though makefile does not allow additional arguments.

```sh
$ make greet foo

hi,
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo'.  Stop.
```

So, I wonder if there're alternatives for command execution.

I hope, although not necessary, there's a tool that satisfies,

1. Cross Platform
2. Allowing additional argument
3. Language neutral
4. Declarative
5. Modern

If there's such a tool, please suggest!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do something akin to:

```
OPSTR ?=

greet:
ifneq( $(OPSTR),)
  echo ”Hi, $(OPSTR)”
else
  echo “Hi”
endif
```

as long as you don’t mind having to remember to define OPSTR:

```
make greet OPSTR=foo
```

Edit: to wrap it in a shell script

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [ “$#” == 1 ];
then
  # warn
fi

make greet “$@“
```

Notice: I’m not sure if passing the whole array would work...

Comment: Thanks! This would be helpful to people who want to use additional args with Makefile. However, I feel it's inconvenient and unnecessarily verbose, that's why I'm finding an alternative.

Comment: If you want, you could wrap the call to <code>greet</code> in a shell script that handles th parsing of OPSTR.